# PCL Kdtree symbol lookup error running program from terminal

Tags: pcl, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm JUST TRYING to run the icp Demo available in the pcl tutorials

I can compile it perfectly... the problem is when i try to run the program in the terminal I get this :

> ./interactive_icp: symbol lookup
> error: ./interactive_icp: undefined
> symbol:
> _ZN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZEEC1Eb

And Yes, I've already tried this :

> sudo apt-get install -f and
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove together with
> erasing build dirs and rebuilding in
> my workspace
>
> rm -r devel rm -r build ...

but it still doesn't work... Can you please help me ? It's been a week and a half all around this and its getting really frustrating since I just want to see the demo running !

I'm running pcl 1.7 with QT creator on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

THANK YOU ALL for your time !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148261/pcl-kdtree-symbol-lookup-error-running-program-from-terminal/) by [Gop](https://answers.ros.org/users/14296/gop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, first make sure all ros packges are upgraded. Call `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. If there are any `ros-...` packages "kept back", then try again with `apt-get distupgrade` or pick them out manually.

After that, rebuild your compelte workspace. As you have shown, it is best to remove devel/build/install. If this doesn't bring success, rinse and repeat, but this time execute the following two commands in order (call `catkin_make` with your parameters) and post the compelte output of both as an edit to your question (its probably best to put them on gist.github.com or pastebin.com and put the link in your question).

```
$ env | grep -i ROS
$ catkin_make [...]
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0